# ASP.NET core 6 app hosted on New web server with IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, deployment

On a new webserver we have installed the ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.3 hosting bundle.

I am trying to make an .net core 6 app to run on this server.

No matter what I do, I cant get it to work.

Webserver: Windows Server 2019
Installed on web server: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

App:
VS 2022.
Asp.net Core 6

I believe that I need to choose the correct publish setup, but I have tried them all, as far as I can see.

Is there anything else I am missing, perhaps on the server?

Comment: At least, you can tell us what exactly is the error. Merely "I can't get it to work" makes it impossible for others to help.

Comment: Is there any error message in event viewer or error page? I think you can show  the web.config and enable log in it. `stdoutLogEnabled="enable" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"`